# Load flow variables with non-string values in ApiGEE

Tags: apigee

I need to save the value of the system variable "system.timestamp" into a flow variable.
(The idea is to obtain the duration of some callout policies in between)

However, I can't read it because the AssignMessage policy raises the fault:

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "Internal Server Error"
        }
    }
}
```

Neither Long nor Integer values can be read, only strings, which is kind of strange because what would be the case of exposing variables one cannot read?

I am trying to avoid the "non elegant" Javascript policy, if that is possible at all, so here's the [very basic] AssignMessage policy I'm using to read the value:

```
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="time-test">
    <DisplayName>TimeTest</DisplayName>

    <AssignVariable>
      <Name>myvar</Name>
      <Ref>system.timestamp</Ref>
    </AssignVariable>

    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

system.timestamp variable is documented here:
 http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/variables-reference#-a-class-jumplink-name-system-a-system-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AssignMessage policy doesn't work, you should be able to accomplish this using a [JavaScript policy](http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api-services/cookbook/programming-api-proxies-javascript).  That would allow you to convert the timestamp to whatever form it needs to be.  Similarly, a JavaScript policy could be used to do any timing calculations or manipulations later on in the proxy.

Comment: Thank you Mike, that's my plan B. I will add the "without a javascript policy" clarification in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Migs, this is a current limitation of the product. I also use system.timestamp in my code, and I solve this problem with a 1 or 2 line JavaScript policy that creates a new string variable named systemTimestamp. I don't know of a better solution currently.

Comment: Thank you ver much Mike, I see you're "Principal architect @ Apigee" so I can't expect anything more official than your answer. In honor of the rules of FIFO, I will mark the previous' Mike answer as the chosen as he suggested the same.